# Error in trying to delete a local publication for DB replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication

I logged in in db ad sa (super admin).

I want to remove a publication made using management studio wizard

(right click on Replication/Local Publications/ New publication)

After trying to delete I have error 15517.

I feel that th subscription i made (it was just a test to explore the replication feature) is slowing down my production db (why did i test on production db i don't know - i wanted to have a local subscription to it from my machine)

Anyway is there a way to delete this publication or at least "freeze" it even if i have thie 15517 error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to replication and right click and select GENERATE SQL SCRIPTS;

1. Then select SELECT ALL in Replication Components Of Scripts;
2. Then select  TO DROP OR DISABLE THE COMPONENTS in Script The Commands;
3. Then select GENERATE SCRIPT button at end;
4. Then Select OPEN IN NEW QUERY;
5. Then the script will be displayed;
6. Then EXECUTE.....